# Selenium Sendkeys C# - Keys.Tab not working

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

Im trying to pass sendkeys by Actions class. Tab is not working.

Tried multiple possible ways like below,

```
1. new Actions(Driver).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab).Perform();
2. new Actions(Driver).KeyDown(Keys.Tab).Perform();
```

Note: Chord is not available in C#

Seeking for a solution in C#

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Try this format. Chords do work in C#.

```
  SendKeys(Keys.Tab);

  or for chord use

  SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a" + Keys.Control);
```

As for adding it to an action, I have not tried that because you would need to find the field that you need to perform the send keys on first. So maybe a move to element and then perform?

```
    public static void test(IWebElement element)
    {
        var actions = new Actions(_webDriver);
        actions.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
        actions.SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Perform();

    }
```

Or the easy way..

```
Driver.FindElement_byId("Field").SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
```